# Create PDF file with file_put_contents()

Tags: php, pdf, xls, createfile

I need to create file from data in SQL. I have base64 string in SQL. I have no problem with images. But the problem is with PDF or XLS files. I use code:

```
$base_64 = 'GENERATE SOME BASE_64 CODE FROM SQL';

file_put_contents('myFile.pdf', base64_decode($base_64));
```

I need help?

Answer (score -1):

It should work, your code seems ok. Make sure your SQL table isn't stripping your base64 code.

`file_put_contents` works PERFECTLY FINE with pdf files